# vim repeat last T movement does not include count

Tags: vim

When invoking `;` to repeat last `T` movement that included a count, the repeat does not repeat the count. ex:

```
 test:  # comment: test
                       ^
                       +-- cursor is here
```

Type: `2T;`

```
 test:  # comment: test
      ^
      +-- cursor is here
```

Make edit, move to next line with the same text, and press `;`, but the movement stops at the first colon

```
 test:  # comment: test
                  ^
                  +-- cursor is here after hitting ;
```

I was surprised that `;` did not repeat the count. Is there something I'm misundertanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> like the equivalent of <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> commands after a search. They just jump to the next match, nothing more. But you can give these commands themselves a count as well.

This is especially useful for getting to the right place, if you guess wrong the first time. E.g. if you really want to jump to the 3rd 'e' character, but you miscount and type `2fe`, then you can simply use <kbd>;</kbd> to get to the correct location.

Comment: I hadn't thought to pass a count to `;` -- brilliant. Thanks